# How do I let the height of the TextView same width as the size of the device screen?

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

I made a 10x10 board , but the visualization gives me rectangles . I was wondering how to create square , leaving the height equal to the width . Could anyone help ?

Java code:

```js
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        chronometer = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabuleiro);

        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);
        gd.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 128));

        final GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        gradientDrawable.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);
        gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.RED);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabuleiro);

        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho_tabuleiro; i++){

            tableRow= new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

            for (int j = 0; j < tamanho_tabuleiro; j++) {


                textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
                textView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        v.setBackgroundDrawable(gradientDrawable);


                    }
                });

                tableRow.addView(textView);
            }

            tableLayout.addView(tableRow, tableParams);
```

Image app:
[image]

Comment: use equal hard coded values in layout param.

Comment: but just used in all wrap_content